# SIMPLE CiviCRM events interface?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

(on Drupal)
Our organisation runs its own annual events with complex ticketing, but we also list a great many events posted by our users, across a number of categories. Some of these can get a bit complex such as one-weekend-a-month modular courses.
We are doing a ground-up site rebuild, and I'm wondering whether to use CiviCRM for all events (so far we have only used it for our big annual ones).

Creating events via the civiCRM backend is probably too daunting for most of our users (plus access control is a challenge) - Is it possible (examples would be good) to create events via a webform?
Or are we best to keep the Date/Calendar/Event modules approach in Drupal?

Comment: Have you looked at Event templates?  If you have a lot of similar events, you can save the common configuration in a template so that staff creating a new event use the template and then update essential details (like description/date) but the rest they can leave alone. https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/events/event-templates/

Answer (score 1):

I looked quickly into doing this with civiCRM entity and rules integration modules (I would think this would be possible), but that seems difficult or not possible without some further customization to set the event parameters.

If you are comfortable with this type of work, I would imagine writing a short module that engages the civiCRM API to create an event on submission of a specific webform could take in the (validated) data from your simplified webform (submitted by a user, doesn't have to be staff) and create the events for you in civiCRM. Using event templates for your categories as Aidan suggested in comments would cut way down on the parameters you would have to feed in for proper configuration. See the API explorer on the relevant version of demo site as a resource for how that might be put together.

Whether doing that work is actually worth it for your use-case, I can't answer for you, depends on how much better it is to have all user events in civiCRM (but I think it would be pretty cool!).